# jvmArguments not interpreted in executable spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I´m trying to build an executable jar with spring boot. It seems like that the jvmArguments that I've configured in the spring-boot-maven-plugin are not interpreted when running the jar on the server.

Here is the part of my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <jvmArguments>-Xmx256m</jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am building the application with:

```
mvn clean package
```

This is how i start my application:

```
[tomcat@dps-8 klstest]$ ./klsprovider-1.1.0.jar --spring.config.name=application-prod
```

And this is where I'm hoping to see the `jvmArguments`:

```
[tomcat@dps-8 ~]$ jps -lvm | grep 33806
33806 /tmp/klstest/klsprovider-1.1.0.jar --spring.config.name=application-prod -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true
[tomcat@dps-8 ~]$
```

Why are the parameters not recognized/interpreted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot executable JAR is build with [`repackage` goal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) which doesn't support `jvmArguments` option. This option is recognized by [`run` goal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html), which will start the application locally during development.

Answer (score 0):

spring-boot-maven-plugin run phase is intended to run your application locally within a Maven process or a Maven forked process depending on configuration. Mainly for test or debugging purpose.

If you have built jar spring-boot-maven-plugin run phase is not applied at all. You need to specify parameters separately for your prod system.

Comment: The Spring Boot maven plugin **is** used when generating a JAR. It is the core piece which creates the specialized Spring Boot fatjar.

Comment: That still doesn't change the fact that it still is being used for building a jar.

Comment: Yes, I am not denying this.